# How to browse through Json data sent from Ajax from PHP program?

Tags: php, json, ajax, data-structures

I am passing a Json array object to a PHP file through Ajax, but I dont know how to receive this and loop through data in PHP.

Here is what I do to get the object named as main data:

```
stringified as json object
var main_data = ["landing_page_id","1",
                 "element",{"workbook_id":15,"workbook":[10,11]},
                 "element",{"workbook_id":15,"workbook":[10,11]}]
```

Here is my Ajax code:

```
$.post('services/addUpdateLandingPage.php', main_data, function(msg)
{
    alert(msg);     
 }, 'json');
```

And, here is my PHP code:

```
$data = $_POST['main_data'];
echo 'this is data'.$data;
```

But, I do not know how to access the data from the PHP file and how to loop through each item ?

Comment: How to handle $_POST data: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp (yes you do Ajax, but the way to handle $_POST is the same), and how to loop through Array: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp, how to handle JSON in PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON should look like this:

> {"landing_page_id":"1","element":[{"workbook_id":15,"workbook":[10,11]},{"workbook_id":15,"workbook":
>   [10,11]}]}

In your PHP code you could get elements data as follow:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($_POST['main_data'],true);
foreach($jsonArray['elements'] as $element){
    echo $element['workbook_id'];
    echo $element['workbook'][0];
    echo $element['workbook'][1];
}
```

In case you dont want to change your json data, you could get elements as follow:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($_POST['main_data'],true);
$isElement = false;
    foreach($jsonArray['elements'] as $element){
        if($element == "element"){
           $isElement = true; 
       }else if($isElement && is_array($element)){
           echo $element['workbook_id'];
           echo $element['workbook'][0];
           echo $element['workbook'][1];
           $isElement = false; 
       }
    }
```

Comment: solution does not seem to work I have tried php returns with no output

Comment: Did you change your json ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing json data through Ajax, You need to decode it in PHP to get passed data.

```
$array = json_decode($main_data,true);  // will output json string to array
```

Loop the above array to get individual data

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value;
    // if $value is array loop again
}
```

Your json data seems to be not in proper structure. Consider structuring in the way Tarun mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I have recieved this object in php how can I loop through in php